# NHibernate support .NET 4.0 framework?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, .net-4.0

Did you anyone used NHibernate with .NET 4.0 framework?

Thanks
SDS

Answer (score 7):

It works without problems.

What is **not** implemented *yet* is support for `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we've used it, it works. Nothing really prevents you from using Nhibernate build that targets earlier frameworks on a newer framework.